# Variable value assignment in Oracle Data Integrator

Tags: oracle-data-integrator

```
<?
String mystr =  "#MY_ODI_VAR";
out.print(mystr);
?>
```

I want to assign value stored in an ODI variable (MY_ODI_VAR) to another variable (mystr) defined inside Java Code in a procedure.
How can this be done. The above mentioned code is producing #MY_ODI_VAR instead of the value assigned to this variable.
I have also tried following variations, but no luck.

Thanks

```
<?
String mystr =  "<% #MY_ODI_VAR %>";
out.print(mystr);
?>

<?
String mystr =  <% "#MY_ODI_VAR" %>;
out.print(mystr);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the question mark tags `<? ?>` the code is generated before ODI variables are substituted.

Using the dollar tags `<$ $>` instead should work. It generates the code after ODI variables are substitued.

```
<$
String mystr =  "#MY_ODI_VAR";
out.print(mystr);
$>
```

Here is a longer explaination about the [4 different substitution tags](https://devepm.com/2014/09/16/odi-substitution-tags-demystified/).